# Trouble writting a code for "wii nunchuck controlling pan tilt servo system"

Tags: nunchuck, servo, arduino, wireless

I have spent days searching for code on the net there is heaps of code for controlling servos for pan/tilt using a wii nunchuck and arduino. However I want to make it wireless, using:

*2 arduino duemilanove boards

*Wii nunchuck

*2x servos

*433MHZ transmitters / recievers

Does anyone know of any code that can be used? OR Can help me be writting some (willing to pay)? OR knows of anyone who can help?

Thanks guys any help would be great

Alex.

Comment: This site isn't really a "do it for me" kind of site. It's more like you attempt to solve something on your own, and then when you have a specific problem where you get stuck, you post the details here and we help. If you want someone to do it for you, you can hire 3rd world people for pretty cheap from places like oDesk / eLance / rentacoder / etc.

Comment: What made you decided to use 433MHz?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are trying to find code that will do everything for you. In the "real" world, it is very unlikely that someone has done the exact same thing as you are wanting to do unless it is something very simple.

What you will need to do is break your project down into very simple blocks. Once you have it broken down you will find it much easier to find code to do what you want it to do for that block. The key for you will be learning how to make all of the blocks interact with each other. If you are not willing to learn how to get these blocks connected, you should look into one of the sites that davr mentioned.

Learning how to connect the blocks will require you to learn how to program and design/interact with hardware, but if you want to do any more projects like this in the future, you will need to learn to do it anyways.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the missing piece is the wireless part. Once you have that, it's "just" a software integration problem.

Have a look at [VirtualWire](http://www.open.com.au/mikem/arduino/VirtualWire.pdf) for controlling cheap 433MHz devices from Arduino. Another option is the [RFM12B](http://news.jeelabs.org/2009/02/10/rfm12b-library-for-arduino/)